# Using useRef to get the height and width gives me TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm attempting to get the `height` and the `width` of `TextInput` using `useRef`, but keeps getting null.

First I tried two different ways to initialize the reference:

```js
const inputRef = useRef(React.createRef)
```

or

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null)
```

And I've matched them with either:

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("inputRef.current.clientHeight", inputRef.current.clientWidth)      
})
```

or

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inputRef.current.clientHeight", inputRef.current.clientWidth)      
})
```

And the element I'm attempting to get the dimension from:

```js
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput 
        ref={inputRef}
        style={styles.textInput}
        label="Chat"
        value={chatMessage}
        onChangeText={setChatMessage}
        onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
        placeholder = "Write a message"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        multiline
        autoFocus
    />
</View>
```

But, I get the following error

> TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'inputRef.current.clientWidth')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native native component layouts don't share the same properties as the Web API.

To access layout information, the docs recommend [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onlayout), but [onContentSizeChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#oncontentsizechange) is an option as well.

I've reproduced a minimal snack, if you'd like a visual inspection of their properties and when they're called: https://snack.expo.io/@ezrayoung/crabby-popsicle (to see the console, click the Editor button at the bottom, and enable the Panel option)